# JSF 2.2 + EJB 3 + JPA on Glassfish 4 and Postgres ConnectionPool

Tags: postgresql, jpa, glassfish, ejb

my application is based on JSF 2.2 EJB 3 JPA on Glassfish 4 with Postgres 9.2 DB. I have create a ConnectionPool and Datasource on Glassfish and I use it on my application through the related Datasource JNDI name.
I have two Facelets pages:

- login.xhtml which calls a BackingBean LoginBacking which calls login method on UserManagement EJB which checks the login by using JPA Persistence Unit. In this case everything works, the user is able to logging in and in case the email is already present the system inform the user that he is already registered.
- registration.xhtml which calls a BackingBean RegistrationBacking which calls register method on UserManagement EJB which persists the user into DB by using JPA Persistence Unit. The registration doesn't work! By looking into Glassfish log I found the following exception:

  ```
          Finer:   client acquired: 553217772
  Finer:   TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
  Finer:   acquire unit of work: 218748741
  Finer:   begin unit of work flush
  Finer:   end unit of work flush
  Finest:   Execute query ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=MomUser sql="SELECT id, classname, company, email, firstname, insertion_date, lastname, password, status, systemuser FROM momuser WHERE (email = ?)")
  Finest:   Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
  Finest:   reconnecting to external connection pool
  Fine:   SELECT id, classname, company, email, firstname, insertion_date, lastname, password, status, systemuser FROM momuser WHERE (email = ?)
  bind => [1 parameter bound]
  Finest:   Connection released to connection pool [read].
  Finer:   TX beforeCompletion callback, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
  Finer:   begin unit of work commit
  Finer:   TX afterCompletion callback, status=COMMITTED
  Finer:   end unit of work commit
  Finer:   release unit of work
  Finer:   client released
  Finer:   client acquired: 1869986747
  Finer:   TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
  Finer:   acquire unit of work: 76560055
  Finer:   TX afterCompletion callback, status=ROLLEDBACK
  Finer:   release unit of work
  Finer:   client released
  Warning:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB MomUserManager, method: public void eu.fabrig.mom.session.MomUserManager.registerUser(eu.fabrig.mom.jpa.entity.MomUser) throws eu.fabrig.mom.exception.UserExistsException
  Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
  ...
  at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: MomUser{id=null, classname=MOMUser, status=A, systemuser=null, insertionDate=null, email=a@c.it, password=098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6, firstname=test, lastname=test, company=Test S.p.A.} is not a known entity type.
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
  ...
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
      ... 54 more

  Severe:   javax.ejb.EJBException
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
  ...
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)    
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: MomUser{id=null, classname=MOMUser, status=A, systemuser=null, insertionDate=null, email=a@c.it, password=098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6, firstname=test, lastname=test, company=Test S.p.A.} is not a known entity type.
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
  ...
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
      ... 54 more

  Info:   ### You can do the cleanup here
  ```

Below my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="eu.fabrig_MOM.PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>myDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <!-- <class>eu.fabrig.mom.jpa.entity.MomUser</class> -->
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Entity and Managed Bean class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "momuser")
@Named
@RequestScoped
@XmlRootElement
public class MomUser implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_seq_gen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq_gen", sequenceName = "mom_seq_id")
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "classname")
private String classname = "MOMUser";
@Column(name = "status")
private Character status = 'A';
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "systemuser")
private String systemuser;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "insertion_date", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date insertionDate;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstname;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "lastname")
private String lastname;
@Size(max = 100)
@Column(name = "company")
private String company;
...
// Getters and Setters
```

Below the EJB method:

```
@Override
public void registerUser(MomUser user) throws UserExistsException {
    try {
        user.setPassword(generateMD5Hash(user.getPassword()));
        em.persist(user);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MomUserManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The Backing bean method:

```
public String register(){
    try {
        MomUser currentMomUser = (MomUser) evaluateEL("#{momUser}", MomUser.class);
        MomUser momUser = userManager.getUser(currentMomUser.getEmail());
        if (momUser != null) {
            getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS));
            return null;
        }
        try {
            userManager.registerUser(currentMomUser);
        } catch (UserExistsException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegistrationBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS));
            return null;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegistrationBacking.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        getContext().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(SYSTEM_ERROR));
        return null;            
    }

    return "login";
}
```

And the registration Facelet:

```
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{bundle['application.registerpage.registrationMessage']}"/>
            </f:facet>

            <h:outputText value="#{bundle['momuser.email']}"/><h:inputText id="email"
                         value="#{momUser.email}"
                         required="true"
                         requiredMessage="#{bundle['momuser.email.validation']}" 
                         validatorMessage="#{bundle['momuser.email.invalid']}">
                <f:validateRegex pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]"/> 
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message for="email" styleClass="errorMessage"/>

            <h:outputText value="#{bundle['momuser.password']}"/>
            <h:inputSecret id="password"
                           value="#{momUser.password}"
                           required="true"
                           requiredMessage="#{bundle['momuser.password.validation']}"></h:inputSecret>
            <h:message for="password" styleClass="errorMessage"/>

            <h:outputText value="#{bundle['momuser.firstname']}"/>
            <h:inputText id="firstname"
                         value="#{momUser.firstname}"
                         required="true"
                         requiredMessage="#{bundle['momuser.firstname.validation']}"/>
            <h:message for="firstname" styleClass="errorMessage"/>

            <h:outputText value="#{bundle['momuser.lastname']}"/>
            <h:inputText id="lastname"
                         value="#{momUser.lastname}"
                         required="true"
                         requiredMessage="#{bundle['momuser.lastname.validation']}"/>
            <h:message for="lastname" styleClass="errorMessage"/>

            <h:outputText value="#{bundle['momuser.company']}"/>
            <h:inputText id="company"
                         value="#{momUser.company}"
                         required="false"/>
            <h:message for="company" styleClass="errorMessage"/>

            
            <f:facet name="footer">
                <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
                    <h:commandButton value="#{bundle['application.registrationpage.proceed']}" action="/registration/registrationconfirm?faces-redirect=true"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{registrationBacking.register}"/>
                    <h:link value="#{bundle['application.registrationpage.gotologin']}" outcome="/login"/>
                    <h:messages globalOnly="true" styleClass="errorMessage"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

Do you have any idea? Why am I able to loggin in but I am not able to register new user?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you uncomment the class in your `persistence.xml`?

Comment: @unwichtich I have tried to uncomment it but still not work.

Comment: I just realized that I missed the fact that you are doing something totally weird. An entity which is at the same time a ManagedBean? And how can the `registerUser` method throw an `UserExistsException`? A normal `EntityManager` doesn't throw this exception or is it coming from `user.setPassword(generateMD5Hash(user.getPassword()));`?

Comment: Totally weird ... maybe but not wrong! If you want you can make an Entity bean managed bean. For what ceoncerns the exception in the EJB method register I removed the part that check if the user already exists because it is not needed for my question. But since you want to know it here the explaination: before calling em.persist(user) I checked with another method if the user Email was already present into the DB and in case the UserExistsException was thrown.

Comment: Crazy stuff :) Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @unwichtich for your answers but I finally found what the problem was and it was caused by my oversight! I imported the wrong @SessionScope, the one coming with JSF context (javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped) instead of the one coming with enterprise context (javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped). Now the registration works!